# How to load glob function in `bzl` file

Tags: bazel

I want to use the `glob` function in `bzl` file, but it seems like that I can't use it directly. So how can I use it in `bzl` file? Or how can I use regular expression in `bzl` file?

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As we can read on [the doc](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/skylark/lib/native.html):

> Note that the native module is only available in the loading phase (i.e. for macros, not for rule implementations).

This basically means you can only use a `glob` function in a .bzl file if this file is a macro called from a BUILD file.

Could you detail your use case?

Regarding regular expressions: They are not available in bzl files.